# How to make camera light strobe in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm using the kphillpotts.Lamp.Plugin to turn the camera flash on/off. Here's my code:

```
private void ButtonFlash_OnPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
    var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);

    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((t) =>
    {
        try
        {
            _lampOn = !_lampOn;
            if (_lampOn)
            {
                CrossLamp.Current.TurnOff();
            }
            else
            {
                CrossLamp.Current.TurnOn();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

        }

    }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
}
```

However, the flash is being turned on/off every 5 seconds or so, when I would expect it to be flashing on/off rapidly. I had to add the try/catch as other wise I get the following error about 2 seconds after the flash first turns on:

```
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
```

Anyone have any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: Throwing exceptions is a very expensive operation, you need to fix that issue and it will run at the desired speed.